# Q_PROPERTY methods can't be called using QMetaObject::invokeMethod()

Tags: qt4, invoke

Good day!

From Qt 4.7.3 docs isn't clear can be properties called using QMetaObject::invokeMethod() or not. But what really strange that are both calls failed:

```
class A : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT

  public:

    Q_PROPERTY( int value READ value )

    int value() { return 0; }

    Q_PROPERTY( int invokableValue READ invokableValue )

    Q_INVOKABLE int invokableValue() { return 0; }
};

...

int returnValue;

QMetaObject::invokeMethod( aPtr, "value"
                           , Q_RETURN_ARG( int, returnValue ) );

QMetaObject::invokeMethod( aPtr, "invokableValue"
                           , Q_RETURN_ARG( int, returnValue ) );
```

It means, that Q_PROPERTY forbids Q_INVOKABLE using.

Let's see a_moc.cpp:

```
      if (_c == QMetaObject::InvokeMetaMethod) {
    // no calls here
    }
    #ifndef QT_NO_PROPERTIES
      else if (_c == QMetaObject::ReadProperty) {
    void *_v = _a[0];
    switch (_id) {
    case 0: *reinterpret_cast< int*>(_v) = value(); break;
    case 1: *reinterpret_cast< int*>(_v) = invokableValue(); break;
    }
```

I think it's time to report bug & feature request, but maybe somehow these problems can be solved?

UPDATE:

Bug [reported](https://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTSDK-1061).

Suggestion [reported](https://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTSDK-1062).

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't post this here, because it's problem description, but not a question.

Comment: You could always turn it into a question by e.g. asking if anyone else had a similar problem, or managed to solve it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the *moc* is not a fully fledged C++ parser, and it can easily misinterpret your code.

It doesn't see the `Q_INVOKABLE` macro because it comes just after the `Q_PROPERTY` declaration. If you add a semi-colon after the property (QtCreator's syntax highlighter won't like that), or if you reorder the lines it will work correctly.

So, for example the following code works:

```
class A : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY( int value READ value )
    Q_PROPERTY( int invokableValue READ invokableValue )
public:
    int value() { return 0; }
    Q_INVOKABLE int invokableValue() { return 0; }
};
```

But I'm not sure why you would want to have an invokable property, since you can already read any property with `QObject::property`.

Comment: It's only for uniformity, because a lot of code using "invoke"-way.

Comment: You are absolutely correct about semicolon. Anyway, I will direct these problems to qt developers.